# Getting information sent from IFRAME WEBVIEW in android

Tags: javascript, android, webview

In Iframe i have funtion postMessage like below

```
               window.parent.postMessage(
                {
                    id: 'Show',
                    data: {
                        live: 10
                    }
                }, "*"
            );
```

Now i load this Frame to webview android

```
private WebView wv;
String html = "<iframe class=\"youtube-player\" style=\"border: 0; width: 100%; height: 95%; 
       padding:0px; margin:0px\" id=\"ytplayer\" type=\"text/html\" src=\"https://example.com" + "?
       fs=0\" frameborder=\"0\">\n" + "</iframe>";
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        wv = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
        wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);        
        wv.loadDataWithBaseURL("", html , "text/html",  "UTF-8", "");

    }
```

Now i want to capture data from id:'Show' of postMessage function.

I search all stackoverflow and google but i can't find any useful information

I have try to use "addJavascriptInterface" but it doesn't work.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView#addJavascriptInterface(java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String)

Could you please show me any code to capture message from JS?
Thanks!!